# etale fundamental group of affine space minus the origin

Tags: algebraic-geometry, fundamental-groups

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic 0. Consider the $n$-th dimensional affine space $\mathbb{A}_k^n$. When $n=1$, I know that  the etale fundamental group $\pi_1^{et}(\mathbb{A}_k^1 - \{0\}) = \hat{\mathbb{Z}}$, since $\mathbb{A}_k^1 - \{0\} = \mathbb{G}_{m,k}$ and the only possible etale covers are of the form $\mathbb{G}_{m,k} \to \mathbb{G}_{m,k}$ given by $x \mapsto x^r$ for $r \in \mathbb{Z}$. My question is, do we have a similar nice characterization in higher dimensions, i.e.

> What is $\pi_1^{et}(\mathbb{A}_k^n - \{0\})$ for $n > 1$?

Comment: There are no non-trivial finite etale covers of $\mathbb{A}^n-\{0\}$ for $n>1$. So, this group should be zero.

Comment: @Mohan Is correct but this is somewhat difficult to show actually. The key theorem is 'purity of the branch locus' which says (roughly) that if $X$ is a locally Noetherian regular scheme and $Z\subseteq X$ is codimension at least $2$ then if $U:=X-Z$ the natural map $\pi_1(U)\to\pi_1(X)$ which is obviously surjective is also injective. In particular, applying this with $X=\mathbb{A}^n$ ($n>1$) and $Z=\{0\}$ shows that $\pi_1(\mathbb{A}^n-\{0\})=\pi_1(\mathbb{A}^n)=0$.